# How to map a list of list to RecyclerView

Tags: android, xml, list, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am trying to map a `List<List<Object>>`  to a RecyclerView in Android, but the result is totally messed up.
For example, I have a list of list like this (just for explaining, not my real case):

```
List<List<String>> list = {{a, b, c}, {d, e}, {f, g, h, i}};
```

the Recyclerview should display like (first row contains three subrows, second has two and the last on has four):

```
|----a-----|  
|----b-----|  
|----c-----|  
|=======|  
|----d-----|  
|----e-----|  
|=======|  
|----f-----|  
|----g-----|  
|----h-----|  
|----i-----|
```

but the result is not exactly like the above order. some element is duplicated and some disappears.   for example:

```
|----d-----|  
|----e-----|  
|----c-----|  
|=======|  
|----d-----|  
|----e-----|  
|=======|  
|----f-----|  
|----a-----|
```

Here is a piece of my code:

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    List<Event> list = eventList.get(position);
    if (holder.rows < list.size()) {
        holder.rowViewGroup.removeAllViews();
        holder.rows = 0;
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        TextView startView = new TextView(context);
        startView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        Event headEvent = list.get(0);
        Calendar startCal = headEvent.getStartCal();
        startView.setText(String.format("%tD", startCal));
        holder.rowViewGroup.addView(startView);

    for (final Event event : list) {
        View element = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.element, null);
        //start time view
        TextView startTimeView = (TextView)element.findViewById(R.id.eventStartTimeInElement);
        Calendar startTimeCal = event.getStartCal();
        startTimeView.setText(String.format("%tl:%tM %tp", startTimeCal, startTimeCal, startTimeCal));
        //end date time view
        TextView endView = (TextView)element.findViewById(R.id.eventEndTimeInElement);
        Calendar endCal = event.getEndCal();
        endView.setText(String.format("%tD  %tl:%tM %tp", endCal, endCal, endCal, endCal));
        //title view
        TextView title = (TextView)element.findViewById(R.id.eventTitleInElement);
        title.setText(event.getTitle());
        //member name

        Drawable divider = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.divider);
        ImageView dividerView = new ImageView(context);
        dividerView.setImageDrawable(divider);
        holder.rowViewGroup.addView(dividerView);
        holder.rowViewGroup.addView(element);
        holder.rows++;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my row.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recycleViewRow">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="2sp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/rowView"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/eventStartTimeInRow"
                />

            </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and element.xml(which is contained by row.xml):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">



    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:id="@+id/eventStartTimeInElement"
            android:layout_weight="2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:id="@+id/eventEndTimeInElement"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left">

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                            
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"                            
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/eventTitleInElement"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
                card_view:cardElevation="2sp"
                card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/memberNameInElement"
                android:gravity="end"
                />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And I know this is not a really good idea to implement this, so could anybody please tell me a better way to implement this? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to flatten your list of lists into one list.

This is just for purposes of the `ListView`.  Your adapter will act as though the lists have all been strung into one long list.

Start by creating a single-list index for all the items of your nested lists.

For example:

```
    List<List<String>> listOfLists = ... // your original data
    List<String> listForView = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (List<String> innerList : listOfLists) {
        for (String str : innerList) {
            listForView.add(str);
        }
        listForView.add("---"); // e.g. marker value for divider
    }
```

Now in your adapter's `getItem()` need only return `listForView.get(position)`.

Anytime your nested list structure changes, you redo this flattening operation and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Things get a little trickier if — given the position — you have to figure out which *list* an item is in, but you could always index the inner lists in a similar fashion.

Comment: But I really want to use CardView to separate each group. What is a better approach to achieve this if I using a flatten list

Comment: xia0guang - I'm looking to do something similar. Have you made any progress?

Comment: AI L-- I use different type of row to solve it. you should try. just override getItemType() and make a bunch of different rows. For my case, I use size of sublist to indicate itemType and use for loop to add different size of sub row. maybe will help you.